# SDL_RenderClear runs slowly

Tags: performance, sdl

I'm new to the SDL library. My task is to falsh up 2000 colors on the screen for 20 secs. Here is my loop that does this:

//renderer inicialization

```
SDL_Renderer *ren = 0;
    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

//loop

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2000; ++i) {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, rand() % 256, rand() % 256, rand() % 256, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(ren);
        SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
        SDL_Delay(10);
    }
```

This runs for about 32 secs on my system. Any idea why does it run for so long?

Answer (score 1):

It is not `clear` but `present` which is limited. You have vsync enabled, and your monitor is 60Hz - meaning it can show 60 different images per second. 2000/60=33.3(3)
You can disable vsync, but it will not change monitor capabilities and will only cause tearing.
Reconsider your problem, e.g. interpolate colours between missing frames.